# Ubuntu 18.04 Hosting ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ubuntu-18.04

I have an exiting ASP.NET MVC4 web project that has been created on a windows 10 machine. 
I want to run this website on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop.
I have been trying for days not and followed several articles about this.

Examples of articels that I followed:

https://blog.todotnet.com/2017/07/publishing-and-running-your-asp-net-core-project-on-linux/

and

https://medium.com/@shrimpy/configure-apache2-mod-mono-to-run-asp-net-mvc5-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-314a700522b9

I have tried to achieve this with Mono and Apache and MonoDevelop.I have struggled with MonoDevelop alone for days, becuase this comes as a dotnet solution pachage with many projects and by default the project doesn't run becuase many project referneces are missing . And once I resolved all of this it still had many problems. So I have given up.

It is possible to develop c# ASP.NET MVC4 website in Visual Studio 2017 and deploy this in Ubunutu 18.04? If so is there any article about this how to do this?

So far I have only managed to run example MVC4 websites on Ubuntu 18.04 that are build and published on Ununto 18.04.

Comment: Could you not able to convert it to ASP.NET Core?

Comment: If you are thinking to do development then +1 for Asp.Net Core

Comment: I will have a look how much work it is to convert my project to ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to run mvc 4/5 on Linux, the best solution is use jexus server from china https://www.linuxdot.net , it can run asp.net mvc and webapi app perfectly on Linux. there is a tutorial https://www.cnblogs.com/shanyou/p/5720733.html

If you can not read chinese, please use google/bing translation.

Comment: Ha I understand now. Jexus runs on Ubuntu. I will give this a shot.

Comment: yes, it runs on ubuntu. you can try the pro version, it includes an embedded version of mono, you can just run your app without  installation of mono.

Comment: After some more research I have decided to go the ASP.NET Core way. Thank you for your answer though but I won't be able to comment further on this.